# Increase width of AppBar leading property

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to put text (custom text button) into leading property of AppBar. However when the text get too long then the text end up in multiple lines

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        leading: Text('Go back to'),
      ),
    )
```

[image]

How do I increase width of AppBar leading property?

I don't want to use title because it makes centering title a PITA.

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: <Widget>[Text('go back to'), Text('My center title')],
        ),
      ),
    )
```

[image]

Is there any way to change it without messing with title property?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set a custom leading width by using the `leadingWidth` property in the `appBar`:

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leadingWidth: 400,
        leading: Text('Go back to'),
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('Center title'),
      ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a predefined widget. You can, however, do this:

```
  appBar: AppBar(
  automaticallyImplyLeading: false, // Don't show the leading button
  title: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      IconButton(
        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.white),
      ),
      // Your widgets here
    ],
  ),
),
```

The `automaticallyImplyLeading: true` will hide the leading button so you can add your own widgets. Good luck!

Comment: I was worry about that... problem Is that I use title property for... well title... if I put row into a title then the title will not be centered  in the appbar... I would have to chase it with Stack which would probably be easier make custom appbar from scratch

Comment: I have updated my question to see why I don't want to use row in title